# ngIf false to true when i click on back button

Tags: angular

I inserted an ngif to make a button invisible on click and then move on to the second component. in the second component I inserted a back button to go back to the first component, when I click on " back" to go to the first component ngif remains false and therefore continues to remain invisible. do you know by chance how to go back and return ngif to true?

button to go to the second component

```
<div>
<a class="butLink" mat-raised-button *ngIf="isButtonVisible" (click)="isButtonVisible = false" 
routerLink="prenotazioni" >Prenota</a>
</div>
```

second component with back button

```
<a class="butLink" mat-raised-button routerLink="">  Indietro</a>
```

thanks a lot to everyone :)

Comment: So the 2 buttons are in 2 separate components? What is the initial value of 'isButtonVisible' in that component. Set isButtonVisible=true when you initialize the first component

Comment: I suspect this can only happen because of the `RouteReuseStrategy`, could it be that `prenotazioni` is a router parameter?

Comment: If it is two component and you are changing the routes the value is going to reset to the it's original value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add either of the following two options in first component

```
isButtonVisible = true;     // declare it as default true
```

OR

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.isButtonVisible = true;  // Initialize it as true
}
```

Note: If first and second components are in same parent component, then move *isButtonVisible* variable to the parent component and assign *default value as true*. Assign *false* when you move to second component, and assign *true* again when you clicks on back button in second component..

Comment: thank you but doen't work... the button rest in false and invisible :/

Comment: when you go back to first component, can you put a console.log inside ngOnInit(isButtonVisible) to check the value